# Flutter test with Mockito package. No stub error

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, mockito

I am facing a NoStub Error when trying to write a test with dependency injection, however, if I use the same code but send the repository through the UseCase's constructor test works fine and passes. Please help me

```js
GetIt injection = GetIt.instance;
// here i set my injection
Future<void> setUpDI() async {
  injection
      .registerFactory<AuthRepositoryInterface>(() => AuthRepositoryImpl());
}

class AuthRepositoryImpl implements AuthRepositoryInterface {
  @override
  Future<bool> login(String phone) {
    print('object');
    return Future.value(true);
  }
}
```

Here I create my Usecase [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1rjW.png)

```js
class LoginUseCase extends UseCase<String, bool> {
  late final AuthRepositoryInterface _repository = injection.get();



  @override
  Future<bool> call(String params) {
    print(_repository.runtimeType);
    return _repository.login(params);
  }
}


@GenerateMocks([AuthRepositoryInterface])
void main() {
  late AuthRepositoryInterface mockRepository;
  late LoginUseCase usecase;

  setUp(() async {
    await setUpDI();
    injection.allowReassignment = true;

    injection.unregister<AuthRepositoryInterface>();
    injection.registerFactory<AuthRepositoryInterface>(
        () => MockAuthRepositoryInterface());

    mockRepository = injection.get<AuthRepositoryInterface>();
    usecase = LoginUseCase();
  });

  tearDown(() => injection.reset());

  test('Testing of login', () async {
    when(mockRepository.login('+994706009073')).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
    print(mockRepository.runtimeType);

    final result = await usecase('+994706009073');
    expect(result, true);
    verify(mockRepository.login('+994706009073'));
  });
```

This works fine if I try to send `mockRepository` to `LoginUseCase` via the constructor

Comment: What is the full error message and stack trace?